# How to increase the `Memory allocatable` of a node in a GCP cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nodes, gcloud

I'm trying to update the Memory allocatable property of a node in Google Cloud Project cluster. I can able to resize the node-pool by adding/removing a node from the node-pool.
Each node of a node-pool now have 2.77GB of memory allocatable. How to increase it to 4GB ?

Answer (score 3):

The machine type cannot be edited on a node pool. You have to add a new node pool to your cluster with the new resources, wait to the ready state of the new pool and delete the old one, the Kubernete will handle creating new pod on the new nodes properly.

Remember if you have some node-selectors based on labels or node properties to copy all you need.